# Problems with the use of variables in powershell

Tags: powershell

I would like to design my script with variables and I have the problem that as soon as I use the variable, my script no longer works.

In the script part, where I specify the PC name structure, I get the error that my variable is not defined.

In the script part where I want to design the replace with a variable, I get the error: No overload can be found for "replace" and the following number of arguments: "1".

The problem occurs once with the $PCSyntax variable and with the $replace variable.

If I run the affected parts of the script without the variables, then it works.

**Script parts without the variables:**

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $AD_Server_Name -Credential $Administrator -ScriptBlock {
$AD_Clients = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "PC-*"' | select-object -Property Name| Export-Csv (Join-Path $using:Export_Pfad_Extern -ChildPath "Active_Directory_Clients.csv") -NoTypeInformation
}
```

```
$WSUS_Clients = Get-WsusComputer -NameIncludes $using:NameSyntax |select FullDomainName| Out-String | % {$_.replace(".domain.local","")} | Out-File -FilePath \\$using:WSUS_Server_Name\C$\users\Administrator\WSUS_Client_list.csv
```

**Script parts with the variables:**

```
$global:PCSyntax = "PC-*"

Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like $using:PCSyntax' | select-object -Property Name| Export-Csv (Join-Path $using:Export_Pfad_Extern -ChildPath "Active_Directory_Clients.csv") -NoTypeInformation
```

```
$global:Replace = ".domain.local",""

$WSUS_Clients = Get-WsusComputer -NameIncludes $using:NameSyntax |select FullDomainName| Out-String | % {$_.replace($using:Replace)} | Out-File -FilePath \\$using:WSUS_Server_Name\C$\users\Administrator\WSUS_Client_list.csv
```

Comment: `-Filter "Name -like $using:PCSyntax"`. Read [about Quoting Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: Now i am getting the error: Error parsing query: "Name -like PC-" Error message: "syntax error" at position: "12".

Comment: Try this: `-Filter "Name -like \`"$using:PCSyntax\`""`

Comment: Can you confirm the two $global: variable assignments are in the main body of your script, and then Get-ADComputer and $WSUS_Clients= are within an Invoke-Command statement? Also, you’ve said you defined those two variables, but you have also defined $NameSyntax outside of the Invoke-Command haven’t you, since you’re referencing it within what I also assume is within an Invoke-Commend (since that's where $using is used) with a $using, and if the Get-WsusComputer in your last example returns nothing there will be no results to pass to Replace.